# Install ubuntu desk top 16.04 after downloading

Tags: live-cd

So I've done what was recommended by backing my files and downloaded ubuntu desktop 16.04. Now from the downloads how do I get it on to a cd in order to install it.  Using the outdated 10.04.

Comment: Do you have a DVD drive or only a CD drive? Does your drive write discs or only read them?

Comment: Which image did you downloaded? Do you have its url?

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to make sure you have a drive that can burn DVDs.  You cannot use a CD as it will not be large enough to hold the image.  Once you have that and a blank DVD, you can just burn the .iso file to the DVD with Brasero, which is installed by default.

Comment: The [minimal ISO](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/MinimalCD) fits on a CD.